# how to get better performance, with not in query

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, mariadb

here is my custom sql query ;

```
SELECT id,
       post_title,
       post_content,
       comment_count,
       post_date,
       post_status,
       post_name
FROM   wp_posts
WHERE  post_type = 'post'
       AND post_status = 'publish'
       AND id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT post_id
                      FROM   wp_postmeta
                      WHERE  meta_key = 'visible_headlane'
                             AND meta_value = 'On')
       AND id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT post_id
                      FROM   wp_postmeta
                      WHERE  meta_key = 'visible_homepage'
                             AND meta_value = 'On')
ORDER  BY post_date DESC
LIMIT  11, 32
```

i can not use, LIMIT in NOT IN Query so, there is any way to use, or limit `SELECT DISTINCT` sql query, or any idea ?

Note : I need to optimise this query because, it takes so long , like a slow query.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps by doing LEFT JOIN combined with IS NULL instead of NOT IN.

Comment: i will do try some about, LEFT join now, anyone has more example or idea. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to `NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM ... )` -- this variation does not need to compute the entire list of things; it only needs to check for the absence.  `LEFT JOIN .. ON .. IS NULL` is also more efficient.

Furthermore, the standard schema for wp_postmeta is quite inefficient; see my [*suggestions*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta).

Meanwhile, keep it as two tests, unlike the suggestion by 'holder'.

The `EXISTS` would look something like

```
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM wp_postmeta
                    WHERE post_id = wp_posts.id
                      AND meta_key = 'visible_headlane'
                      AND meta_value = 'On' )
```

which would make good use of the `PRIMARY KEY(post_id, meta_key)` that I recommend.

(Is it really 'headlane', not 'headline'?)

Comment: thanks for the smart answer. happy great one for you @rick james

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this as jarlh suggested

```
SELECT 
ID,post_title,post_content,comment_count,post_date,post_status,post_name
FROM wp_posts t1
left join  (
SELECT DISTINCT post_id from wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key IN ('visible_headlane','visible_homepage') AND meta_value = 'On' ) t2 on t1.ID = t2.post_id

WHERE post_type = 'post'
AND post_status = 'publish'
AND t2.post_id is null
ORDER BY post_date DESC
LIMIT 11, 32
```

Comment: its good bot not really better, it takes again 15.6 ms execute time.

Comment: Also added, LIMIT it takes 13 ms; 
`left join  (
SELECT DISTINCT post_id from wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key IN ('visible_headlane','visible_homepage') AND meta_value = 'On' order by post_id  DESC LIMIT 11,32) t2 on t1.ID = t2.post_id`